# Footsteps too fast without delay in them

Tags: unity-game-engine, wwise

Hi I'm trying to implement my footsteps for a game using Wwise but they are way too fast and I can't change the speed. I made a random container with different footstep sounds, then added the script. However ! it is playing the footsteps really fast in succession. I tried adding wwise silence between the footsteps in a sequence container, but that didn't change anything. I need the footsteps to be random, but i want to be able to control the time between each footstep.

The game is in first persone so i can't put it on an animation. How do I do it?

I tried to put the souns in a sequence container but it doesn't change anything. I also tried to put the player footsteps event with a top and delay but nothing happens either.

Comment: Hello . A lot of your question depends on the setup of your AudioClips and the Script you are using. If you could provide more insight into your project, we are maybe able to help you.

Comment: if(direction != Vector3.zero) {bruitDePas.Post(gameObject);} i ended up doing something different to play the event from time to time if (direction != Vector3.zero) { nbrPas++; if (nbrPas > vitessePasSon) { //lancer event bruit de pas bruitDePas.Post(gameObject); nbrPas = 0; } }

Comment: Is this issue still relevenat?